# How can I give access to only a single Google Analytics 4 (GA4) report?

Tags: report, share, google-analytics-4, restrict

I need to give a client access to only a single report in Google Analytics 4. This report is filtered to show page views only for a certain subdirectory of the website. I find that I have to share the entire property, which gives the client access to data for the entire website. Apologies if I missed this in my web searches, but I'm beginning to think there's no way to do what I'm trying.

Any advice or other way to go about this entirely? Would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the option to view certain information is not available in GA4. However, there are some alternative solutions that might be helpful.

1. You can create a Looker Studio dashboard and share the results with full control through it.
2. You can send your data to Bigquery and create desired reports, defining row level access and column level access to each participant.
3. You can add a new container to the targeted page and a new GA4 account with limited events and tracking. (this may not be the best option, but it can work)